# finding hyperplane from 2d data points for svm without libraries

Tags: python, svm

So, I am working on a project for school and I am stumped. The project is to make a program capable of training an SVM on simple linearly separable 2d data. The only thing that is supplied to our program is a numpy of data  points and their respective labels. I am so confused and lost. The functions I am supposed to write are:

[w, b, S] = svm_train_brute(training_data)

dist = distance_point_to_hyperplane(pt, w, b)

margin = compute_margin(data, w, b)

y = svm_test_brute(w, b, x)

where S is the support vectors for the supplied training data. Each of the functions after svm_train_brute are suggested in the project description as being necessary to training the svm, however, I can't figure out how to even start this. Each of these helper functions requires w and b, but I have no idea how to find w and b given the training data. If i knew which points were support_vectors, then I think I might be able to find w and b given y(wx +b) = 1 for the support vectors but I cant think how to find the support vectors. I tried using a similar approach to peceptrons to find w and b with no luck. I just need help trying to figure this out.
How can i find w and b using y(wx + b) = 1 or otherwise find the hyperplane? thank you for any help and sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Can you do it for a toy 2D example of `(x, y)` points on a plane? Understand the math behind it first, then start with the coding part.

Comment: @swag2198 I tried this with a "test" data set supplied for the project; [-5,0,1], [-4,0,1], [-3,0,1], [-2,0,1], [-1,0,1], [1,0,-1], [2,0,-1], [3,0,-1], [4,0,-1], [5,0,-1]. I found the midpoint between the two closest points with opposite labels, then concluded the midpoint was on the hyperplane. If I solve a system of eqs using y(wx + b) = 1 for the two closest points (calling them support vectors) and wx + b = 0 with the midpoint it would solve w and b, but will this work when there are more then two support vectors? Will the midpoint of the two closest points  always be on the hyperplane?

Comment: SVM intends to solve an optimization problem. You fill find the formal treatment in any standard ML book or in the internet. Understand the optimization problem and learn how to solve it.